# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c++/cli

Tags: foreach, c++-cli

I keep getting "System.NullReferenceException" with "Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I done exactly the same thing in the former for each statement braces and the error was not thrown. Can someone please explain why because I don't understand.

```
array<System::Byte ^> ^temp_2 = gcnew array<System::Byte  ^>(4);
System::Int32 count_1 = 0;

for each (System::Byte ^element in temp_2) 
{
    count_1 += 1;
    element = gcnew System::Byte;
    element = System::Byte::Parse(count_1.System::Int32::ToString());
    System::Console::WriteLine(element->System::Byte::ToString());
};

count_1 = 0;
for each (System::Byte ^element in temp_2) 
{
    count_1 += 1;
    System::Console::WriteLine(element->System::Byte::ToString()); *// throws error here//*
};
```

Comment: `Byte^` is the wrong thing to do.  `System::Byte` is a value-type, I promise you don't want to use a tracking handle to it.  Your `element` is not a reference to a member of the array, it's a copy of an element of the array (which is in turn a reference).  When you change `element`, you're changing the copy to refer to some new object, but you aren't changing the array.  Ditch all the `Byte^` and just use `array<Byte>`

Comment: @ben-voigt So you only use the top level ^ to denote reference types in the CLI? When you say ' it's a copy of an element ' your saying it's a pointer to the same thing as an element in the array is pointing to. Setting aside the differences between the terminology of references/pointers ( i.e. treating as same thing).

Comment: Yes it is a handle to the same boxed byte the array element points to. But you aren't actually changing the byte pointed to, which would be visible in the array, but reseating the handle to point to another boxed byte.

Comment: @ben-voigt So I have the following after the code of the corrected version.`for each(System::Byte element in temp_2)
 {
  element = System::Byte::Parse("23");
 };` I attempted to dereference the pointer and set all bytes in the array to 23. The values of the array have not changed. Have I incorrectly dereferenced the pointer to modify the values in the byte array. A corrrected version of deferencing the pointer `element` would be very helpful.

Comment: Try `for each (System::Byte% element in temp_2)`  do not add % to the array type, only to the for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
element->System::Byte::ToString()
```

to

```
element->ToString()
```

ToString is not a static function. It is a member function of class System::Object and correspondingly is inherited by System::Byte.

I do not know C++/CLI very well but as far as I know you should use ordinary for loop if you want to change elements of a container.
Try to change

```
for each (System::Byte ^element in temp_2) 
{
count_1 += 1;
element = gcnew System::Byte;
element = System::Byte::Parse(count_1.System::Int32::ToString());
System::Console::WriteLine(element->System::Byte::ToString());
};
```

to

```
for ( int i = 0; i < temp_2.Length; i++ ) 
{
count_1 += 1;
temp_2[i] = gcnew System::Byte;
temp_2[i] = System::Byte::Parse(count_1.System::Int32::ToString());
System::Console::WriteLine(temp_2[i]->ToString());
}
```

Comment: It worked, I'm in future using that to iterate through my arrays, for each in does something strange with the objects. Thank you.

Comment: @user3246323, for each didn't do anything strange, you just never saved the references to the bytes into the array.  You'll notice in the first loop you don't use the element out of the array at all: you just assign to the reference.  That doesn't update the array to have that reference. So, the array continues to hold on to a null reference.

Comment: for each does not allow to change elements of a container.

Comment: @matt-smith Could you give me a correct version using the For each in like I attempted to do, it would help me get my head around it. Would be very grateful.

Comment: @matt-smith Doesn't matter, refreshed the page saw Vlad comment, thank you all for the help.

Comment: @In euser3246323, I was never suggesting to change the elements from within the for each loop.  I was just trying to point out that it is not true that "for each does something strange with the objects".  You just never changed the container, so it remains full of nulls.

Comment: @matt-smith Ok, I thought element stood for the item in the array and you could assign bytes to an item in the container by using the identifier 'element'. For each in statement is used in other situations I presume.

Comment: @Ineuser3246323, it is a reference to what is in the array.  There are two references (the one in the array and `element` in the for each loop).  They both start out pointing to `nullptr`, but in the loop you change what `element` points to.  You do not however change what the reference in the array points to.  In the new version presented here, there is only one reference (the one in the array) and that is the one changed within the loop.

Comment: @matt-smith If it is a reference/pointer to what's in the array, using the original code, shouldn't I be able to dereference it to assign an item a value. Or does it point to a copy of an item in the array. Documentation of it on msdn is vague.

Comment: @Ineuser3246323, The array doesn't contain the object it contains a reference.  Reference R1 in the array points to null originally.  Reference R2 in the for each loop also originally points to null (i.e. it gets a reference pointing to the same thing that the array points to--it doesn't point to the array).  In your loop you update R2, that has no effect on R1.  Think of it likes `object ^ o1 = nullptr; object ^ o2 = o1; o2 = gcnew object();`  In this case updating o2 doesn't affect o1.  o1 still points to null.

Comment: @matt-smith Ok, that has seriously clarified it for me. One last thing, can I dereference the reference so I can assign what it points to then?

Comment: @Ineuser3246323, dereferencing the the reference would allow you to modify the object that it points to, but there is no way with a given reference to change all other references that point to that object to point to some new object. In your case, you don't need it.  When you want to change the the references in the array, use the name of the array as in this answer.

Comment: "for each does not allow to change elements of a container" -- only mostly correct, see my answer for why it *is* possible to change elements of an array using `for each` (and the right syntax), but only on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `array<Byte^>` results in putting tracking handles in the array, and not handles *to* the array, has been pretty well covered in comments by both Vlad and myself.

However, contrary to Vlad's conclusion, it *is* possible to use `for each` to mutate elements of an array.  This works (tested in VS2010):

```
// cppcli_foreach_reference.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdint.h" // gives System::Byte the nice short name uint8_t

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<uint8_t> ^temp_2 = gcnew array<uint8_t>(4);
    uint32_t count_1 = 0;

    for each (uint8_t% element in temp_2) 
    {
        count_1 += 1;
        element = System::Byte::Parse(L"43");
        System::Console::WriteLine(element.System::Byte::ToString());
    }

    count_1 = 0;
    for each (uint8_t element in temp_2) 
    {
        count_1 += 1;
        System::Console::WriteLine(element.System::Byte::ToString());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The way it works is that it binds a tracking reference to each array element.  Updates through the tracking reference, like a native C++ reference, actually affect the original object.  Unlike putting pointers inside the array, this really is (syntactic sugar for) a pointer *into* the array.

However, note that this only works for arrays.  Other collection types do not provide access to the actual content of the collection, they provide an indexer property with a getter that returns a copy of the value and a setter that copies a new value to the content.  And enumerators that return a copy from `IEnumerator<T>.Current`.

It's only arrays, which are a special case for `for each` that bypasses `IEnumerator<T>`, that can be updated in `for each`.

Comment: Thank you, I am awfully grateful for the explanations. I wouldn't have got anywhere without this. On the msdn it said "When identifier is a tracking reference, you can modify the element.". I originally didn't understand what this meant but now I do. When I get to your experience level I'll contribute answers to webbased forums like this because it's a resource people cannot do without and should forever exist like a public library.

Answer (score -1):

You ended your `for each` statements with `semi-colon` which should not be used in this case.

Edit: Removed a wrong statement.

"In your post when I formatted it I noticed you called it `for each` instead of `for_each`, "

Comment: The semicolon is harmless. Bad style, but not causing any problem.